# 301 Redirects on Products in DNN

Tags: asp.net, redirect, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

I am a novice when it comes to developing and coding. I am stronger at design and HTML/CSS but I have a question regarding 301 redirects on a eCommerce site that I am getting ready to launch.

The site has over 500 products and the URLs for these products are now different. I need a way to create a redirect map so that I don't have to redirect 500+ products manually.

The old URLs look like this: domainofstore.com/Animated-Waving-Santa.html

The new URLs look like this: domainofstore.com/Product/animated-waving-santa

The new site is built in DNN 9 with RevIndex StoreFront.

Now there are some static pages that need to be redirected as well and I have no problem creating those manually. There URL structure is below:

Old URL: domainofstore.com/About-The-Holiday-Light-Store.html

New URL: domainofstore.com/About-Us

So how do I go about creating the 500+ product URL rewrites without having to add them manually?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same situation with an ecommerce re-platform to DNN where we needed to programmatically redirect the old style product page Urls to the new Urls in DNN.  I ended up writing a custom [Url Extension Provider](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/extension-url-providers) in DNN to accomplish this.

I do have a step-by-step tutorial on DNNHero.com, but it does require a subscription.  Is is called: [Building a URL Extension Provider for DNN](https://www.dnnhero.com/video/introduction-and-url-rewriting-basics).

Answer (score 0):

These are not by strong points, but ... DNN has URL rewriting capabilities.  So does IIS.  There are also a URL Adapter module from DNNSharp and a free OpenUrlRewriter module on Github.

One or more of these should do the trick if you can come up with a rule to match the old URLs.

And, have you asked RevIndex for help with this issue?

Comment: I have found some rewrite modules and generators that work but those are doing it manually. I really need to find a rewrite map that will work for the URL structure I have.

RevIndex was no help as they stated "you are on your own with the redirects".

Comment: Seems like if the rule could take the “/Animated-Waving-Santa.html” and replace it with “/Product/animated-waving-rule” by taking the html name and replacing it with the same name stripping the “.html” out and adding the “/Product/” in front of it, it would work. I just have no idea how to code a rewrite map in .ASP to work like that.